# Cannot insert the value NULL into column when I try to insert it from text box but works fine when I insert it directly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am not able to INSERT the data into database when I try to insert the data from the text box with ID="USERNAME" that is by selecting the VALUES as @USERNAME e.g.:InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table12] ([USERNAME]) VALUES (**@USERNAME**)". 
But the same works absolutely fine if I don't opt to insert the data from the above text box.

I am getting below error if I were to use the above code in for INSERT statement.

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'USERNAME', table 'D:\LOGINCONTROL\LONGINCONTROLTEM\LONGINCONTROLTEM\APP_DATA\ASPNET-LONGINCONTROLTEM-20150905150101.MDF.dbo.Table12'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

**Below statement works fine but not the above, as in the text "SOME VALUE" is inserted into the database correctly, once I click the button, which proves that there is no connection issue here.**

e.g.:InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table12] ([USERNAME]) VALUES (**'SOME DATA'**)".

**Below is the complete code that I am using.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="INPUTTODATABASE.aspx.cs" Inherits="LongincontrolTem.INPUTTODATABASE" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="testtest" runat="server">

      User Name:   <asp:TextBox ID="USERNAME" value="" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="SaveData" runat="server" Text="InsertData" OnClick="SaveData_Click" />


        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertInformation" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet"
          ConnectionString="Data Source=DECTO-PC;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LongincontrolTem-20150905150101.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table12] ([USERNAME]) VALUES (@USERNAME)"
          ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" >


<InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="USERNAME" Type="Char" />

    </InsertParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

// **code behind page**
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace LongincontrolTem
{
    public partial class INPUTTODATABASE : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource DataSourced = (SqlDataSource)FindControl("InsertInformation");



            DataSourced.Insert();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried everything on internet but didn't find any answer for above. I am a new programmer and feel like this is a silly question that I am asking but guys any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever setting the value of the parameter.  As a result, it defaults to NULL.  I hate to just point you to a link, but have you looked at the example in this page?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkzs2t3h.aspx.  It shows (among lots of other things) how to use a TextBox control to provide a value for a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ann. Do you think that's the only issue? Because I tried changing the values and fields of parameter but unfortunately none of my tricks worked out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of minor changes needed to get this working:

First, your `InsertParameters` should refer to your TextBox, as this is what you need to supply the value. Also, you probably need a type of `String` rather than `Char`. Try replacing that block with something like:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="USERNAME" Type="String" ControlID="USERNAME" />
</InsertParameters>
```

Next, your `SaveData_Click` event can be simplified:

```
protected void SaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertInformation.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Michael McMullin - You are just awesome mate!!! It is working now... Thank you very much :)